# Maven Build Asks for log file and (Permission Denied)

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, openstack

I have an opensource Maven project which I downloaded from GitHub.The project is called ElasticInbox (https://github.com/elasticinbox/elasticinbox.git).

When I try to build the project I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/var/log/elasticinbox/elasticinbox.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/log/elasticinbox/elasticinbox.log (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/log/elasticinbox/elasticinbox.log (Permission denied)
at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:28)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:149)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:108)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:72)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:96)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:318)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:197)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:183)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:157)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:143)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:106)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:56)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:148)
at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
at  at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.Activator.<clinit>(Activator.java:58)
at  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:151)
at  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:751)
at  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
at  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:374)
at  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1067)
at  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:561)
at  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:546)
at  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:459)
at  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
at  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:440)
at  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
at  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:337)
```

Initially the error was file not found then I manually created this log file via the terminal. As far as I understand, this is not the project code which is executing. It seems to be the maven build which is throwing this error and I a not able to proceed further.

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the access to your file location is not shared with others. Hence you are getting permission denied issue.

In `logback.xml` file, https://github.com/elasticinbox/elasticinbox/blob/master/config/logback.xml
the location of log file has been specified. Try changing its path to your user dir, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered the exactly same issue, you can have the following check:

1. ensure the `path` is correct - prefixed with `/` means an absolute;
2. the current user has proper permission to write into the file - check it with `sudo ls -alh path_to_the_file`, if not then use `sudo chown -R user:user the_parent_folder_name` to change it;

I fixed it by removing the entire folder first and then create a new folder with proper owner.